# Retrieve rows which have comma separated values in corresponding column

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some category list. And have some posts those have multiple category.
such as ..

**php** is a category,, The first post has **php**, JavaScript, WordPress category and the second post has **php**, MySQL category in one column.

Now when I click on the **php** category, that time all the posts which have **php** category will be retrieved.

please any idea how can I retrieve all posts based on one category if those has multiple category in one column.

Comment: Can't you use SQL query with `column LIKE '%php%'`?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla What about `C` `C#` `C++` ??

Comment: you have comma separated values in column ?

Comment: He tagged PHP and Mysqli..!! @sagi.. just look!

Comment: .... @ShaunakShukla , In the comma separated column

Comment: Really a bad design flaw; you should be using a 1-many table for post_categories; any other solution is a bad workround

Comment: I so sorry for the bad design. I am new in `php` and `mysqli`. I do not understand what you want to mean by 1-many table. Please explain that.

Comment: I mean that you shouid create a post_category table with a post_id and category columns, and store each post/category combination as a separate row in that new table; not in a comma-separated list in the posts table

Comment: Your code is working @ShaunakShukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL function.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET('PHP', category_column);
```

`FIND_IN_SET()` returns **position** of the `PHP` in `category_column`, so used in `WHERE` clause it is a `true` for everything except `0`, which is returned when substring was not found.

As a disclaimer I'd like to mention, that it seems, you have bad design of your database. You shouldn't put multiple values in one field. You may get in trouble with developing further features in you app later.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, your code is working. I am new in php and mysqli so that is my fault of bad design. Ok, I will try to do best further.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), something like..

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('php',`your_colum_name_containing_values`);
```